# Set limit of posts to display in jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I need to limit the number of posts that show in a list from a collection of many posts. I am currently checking each post with a category of a specific name and then breaking the loop after the first 4 posts have been found.

```
{% assign count = 0 %}
 {% for post in site.faqs %}
  {% if post.faq_category contains "category-name" %}
   {% assign count = count | plus:1}
    {% if count == 4 %}
    {% break %}
        <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, this is not returning any results. I'm not sure if I just have the count in the wrong place or what.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I had to set the count below the `li` element:

```
{% assign count = 0 %}
      {% for post in site.faqs %}
        {% if post.faq_category contains "category-name" %}
          {% assign count = count | plus:1 %}
          <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
          {% if count == 4 %}{% break %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: you could also just use `{% for post in site.faqs limit: 4 %}` to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

Using the counter you can filter posts and just display when the counter is less than 4, otherwise use `break` as you did:

```
{% assign count = 0 %}
{% for post in site.faqs %}
  {% if post.faq_category contains "category-name" %}
   {% assign count = count | plus:1}
    {% if count < 4 %}
    <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

A cleaner version can be done creating the array of `faqs` items of the desired category and then limiting the for loop to 4:

```
{% assign faqs = site.faqs | where_exp:"item",
"item.faq_category contains 'category-name'" %}
<ul>
{% for post in faqs limit:4 %}
<li>{{post.title}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```